# Pycharm gives error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable" in debug mode for Python-Django Project

Tags: python, django, pycharm, virtualenv

I have set up the `python-django` project in Pycharm.

On `python manage.py runserver` command in run mode, its works fine but when I run the project in debug mode I get following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usmanmaqbool/Downloads/pycharm-community-2018.3/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 2060, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/usmanmaqbool/Downloads/pycharm-community-2018.3/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 2054, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/home/usmanmaqbool/Downloads/pycharm-community-2018.3/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1405, in run
    return self._exec(is_module, entry_point_fn, module_name, file, globals, locals)
  File "/home/usmanmaqbool/Downloads/pycharm-community-2018.3/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1412, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/home/usmanmaqbool/Desktop/proj/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/usmanmaqbool/Envs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/usmanmaqbool/Envs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/usmanmaqbool/Envs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/usmanmaqbool/Envs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 58, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/usmanmaqbool/Envs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/usmanmaqbool/Envs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 97, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "/home/usmanmaqbool/Envs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 106, in run
    autoreload.main(self.inner_run, None, options)
  File "/home/usmanmaqbool/Envs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 333, in main
    reloader(wrapped_main_func, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/usmanmaqbool/Envs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 304, in python_reloader
    exit_code = restart_with_reloader()
  File "/home/usmanmaqbool/Envs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 290, in restart_with_reloader
    exit_code = os.spawnve(os.P_WAIT, sys.executable, args, new_environ)
  File "/home/usmanmaqbool/Downloads/pycharm-community-2018.3/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_monkey.py", line 496, in new_spawnve
    return getattr(os, original_name)(mode, path, args, env)
  File "/home/usmanmaqbool/Envs/proj/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 573, in spawnve
    return _spawnvef(mode, file, args, env, execve)
  File "/home/usmanmaqbool/Envs/proj/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 549, in _spawnvef
    elif WIFSIGNALED(sts):
  File "/home/usmanmaqbool/Envs/proj/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 549, in _spawnvef
    elif WIFSIGNALED(sts):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have also created new Virtua ENV and same issue with new virtual ENV too!

**EDIT 1**

Database settings:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'db_name',
    'USER': 'user',
    'PASSWORD': 'passworf',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

A few days ago it was working fine but after the new update version of Pycharm, I am facing this issue on just one project.

Comment: Can you share your Database settings in settings.py?

Comment: @cagrias I have updated!

Comment: can you update `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql'` ?

Comment: can you please tell me the reason for it? I am asking because it's working fine in run mode and even for other Django projects.

Comment: I have updated it but still same issue!

Comment: since Django 1.9, the name of the engine is changed to 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql'. But obviously that is not the problem

Comment: I am using Django 1.10.5

Comment: Check that in 1.10 documentation, you need to add it as `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql'`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#engine

Comment: But I'm not sure if that's the reason for your problem

Comment: I also tried it but the error is same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a regression in PyCharm 2019.2 debugger for some Python versions, e.g. old 2.7.x https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-36726

The fix is ready and will be included in the 2019.2.1 minor update, the preview build will be live this week.

Answer (score 1):

Release 2019.2.1 is now available and fix this bug.

[image: Release 2019.2.1 details]

Update your version of PyCharm as follow:

Go to `File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behaviour -> System Settings -> Updates`

Press `Check Now` then `Update`